# Concatenate with respect to 1st dimension

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

In the following code what does `torch.cat` really do. I know it concatenates the batch which is contained in the sample but why do we have to do that and what does concatenate really mean.

```
 # memory is just a list of events
 def sample(self, batch_size):
    samples = zip(*random.sample(self.memory, batch_size))
    return map(lambda x: Variable(torch.cat(x,0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

`torch.cat` concatenates as the name suggests along specified dimension.

Example from documentation will tell you everything you need to know:

```
x = torch.randn(2, 3) # shape (2, 3)
catted = torch.cat((x, x, x), dim=0) # shape (6, 3), e.g. 3 x stacked on each other
```

Remember concatenated tensors need to have the same dimension **except the one along which you are concatenating**.

In the above example it doesn't do anything though and isn't even viable as it lacks second argument (inputs to apply `map` to), see [here](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#map).

Assuming you would do this mapping instead:

```
map(lambda x: Variable(torch.cat(x,0)), samples)
```

It would create a new tensor of shape `[len(samples), x_dim_1, x_dim_2, ...]` provided all `samples` have the same dimensionality except `0`.

Still it is pretty convoluted example and definitely shouldn't be done like that (`torch.autograd.Variable` is deprecated, see [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#variable-deprecated)), this should be enough:

```
# assuming random.sample returns either `list` or `tuple`
def sample(self, batch_size):
   return torch.cat(random.sample(self.memory, batch_size), dim=0)
```